# Careers : Add Question - 500 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I've a bug to report on [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).

When I click the add answer link on my careers profile, insert a link in the box and click the add link in the front of the question i get a 500 internal server error from the save page (marked in the image bellow)
[image: The button that throws the error on-click.]

Request Data:

```
Request URL:http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/widgets/stackexchangeanswers/addAnswerToCV?answerId=10213324&site=Stack+Overflow
Request Method:GET
```

Response:

```
Status Code:302 Found
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:60
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:184
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 08 Jun 2012 12:34:54 GMT
Location:/error?aspxerrorpath=/cv/widgets/stackexchangeanswers/addAnswerToCV
X-User-Id:165061
X-User-Type-Id:3
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Comment: A fix for this will go out monday morning.

Comment: Thank you @NickLarsen, the problem is solved and the questions are now working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes are out, thanks for the report.

Comment: Thank you for the quick support, now I have my profile completed :)